# Ungrouped ones in karnaugh map

Tags: boolean-logic, karnaugh-map

[image: QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS PLEASE CLICK]

There are ungrouped ones in the answers to the questions I showed in the picture.Bottom one is my solving style but the right answer is upper pic .Shouldn't we group each one in the map?  What is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawing is a little unclear I think.

If you read the actual answer, you'll notice that there are two options for the final grouping:

```
A'BD
 or
BCD
```

BCD is the grouping in red in your answer, while A'BD is the grouping:

[image: A'BD grouping]

So there are two options for grouping that lone 1, and the answer considers both of them. It just doesn't *draw* both of them.

---

The giveaway is that a single cell needs 4 terms to specify it -- that `1` on its own would be `A'BCD`. However there aren't any elements with 4 terms in the answer, which means that the answer must have grouped it with another cell.

Comment: I wasn't sure what the correct answer was because I didn't see the grouping process in the Karnaugh map. Thank you for making that clear.